# Connecting TFS to TeamCity

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, connection, teamcity, autodeploy

I'm trying to connect my TeamCity project to my TFS project with a free account (a windows live account). But I'm having a little bit a trouble doing this. I'm getting the error TF30063 (You are not authorized to access /DefaultCollection/).
I've tried a lot of things, I even follow the instruction of this question -http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-20909-, but no luck...

I already have:
- Set admin permission to all members to my TFS project
- Put the project on my computer in a public folder
- Checked every url, user and password inputs on the TeamCity config page
- Tested in more than one TFS account
- Checked if all projects were in the same domain
- I've tested in a network that doesn't uses proxy and one that does

Neither of these configuration seem to make a difference... The only lead I have to why this problem is happening is because I'm using the Windows Live (free) TFS account and not a paid licensed one... Can that be it?

Any help would be appreciated... Cheers!

Here is the full error:

---

Failed for the root 'DimasTeste' #16: TFS failed. ExitCode: 111, command: C:\TeamCity\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\plugins\tfs\bin\tfs-native.exe @@C:\TeamCity\temp\TC-TFS-108-6176_396\command.params, in file: {https://budiedimas.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/, /user: /password: /hash:S, /noProxy, C:\TeamCity\temp\TC-TFS-108-6176_393.result, GetCurrentVersion}, completed in: 2 second(s) 
stdout: TFS Native Verifier v8.0 Copyright (C) 2006-2013 JetBrains s.r.o.
Running under .NET Framework 4.0.30319.18052
INFO - 
INFO - Use Team Explorer 2012
INFO - 
TFS Native Accessor v8.0 Copyright (C) 2006-2013 JetBrains s.r.o.
INFO - Connecting to server https://budiedimas.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/
INFO - WebProxy is disabled
Get current version:
Server='https://budiedimas.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/'
Username='dimas_budie@hotmail.com'
ERROR - TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://budiedimas.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/.
System.Exception: TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://budiedimas.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/. ---> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerUnauthorizedException: TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://budiedimas.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/.
em Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.EnsureTokenProvider(HttpWebResponse webResponse)
em Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.SendRequest()
em Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpRequestChannel.Request(TfsMessage message, TimeSpan timeout)
em Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.Invoke(TfsClientOperation operation, Object[] parameters, TimeSpan timeout, Object[]& outputs)
em Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.Registration.GetRegistrationEntries(String toolId)
em Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.RegistrationProxy.GetRegistrationEntries(String toolId)
em Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.RegistrationService.GetInstanceId()
em Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.RegistrationService.get_InstanceClientCacheDirectory()
em Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.RegistrationService..ctor(TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsObject)
em Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection.CreateServiceProxy(Type serviceType)
em Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection.GetServiceInstance(Type serviceType, Object serviceInstance)
em Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.GetService(Type serviceType)
em Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.PreFrameworkServerDataProvider.FindServiceLocation(String serviceType, String toolId)
em Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.PreFrameworkServerDataProvider.LocationForCurrentConnection(String serviceType, Guid serviceIdentifier)
em Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.EnsureProviderConnected()
em JetBrains.TeamCity.Tfs.Command.Do() na c:\BuildAgent\work\23f504c63c17dfdf\TfsNativeAccessor\src\Command.cs:linha 28
em JetBrains.TeamCity.Tfs.Program.Main(String[] args) na c:\BuildAgent\work\23f504c63c17dfdf\TfsNativeAccessor\src\Program.cs:linha 143
--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha de exce‡äes internas ---
em JetBrains.TeamCity.Tfs.Program.Main(String[] args) na c:\BuildAgent\work\23f504c63c17dfdf\TfsNativeAccessor\src\Program.cs:linha 438

Answer (score 4):

You should enable alternate credentials (basic authentication) for your account.

http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2012-aug-27/

Go to your profile -> credentials -> enable alternate credentials. Then use them in TeamCity.

[image]

Comment: Try to access TFS with standard GIT client, for example. If you can't - then the problem is not in TeamCity.

Answer (score 0):

Team Foundation Service is supported only on TC 7.1.4+.
Which version are you running?

http://blogs.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/02/07/teamcity-7-1-4-build-24331-is-ready/comment-page-1/#comment-38321