# Connecting TeamCity to Visual Studio Online

Tags: tfs, teamcity, azure-devops

I'm having trouble connecting TeamCity server (TeamCity Enterprise 8.0.6 (build 27767)) to Viusal Studio Online.  I have searched and read many articals with the following being helpful : -

[Connecting TeamCity to TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446930/conecting-teamcity-to-tfs)

[Connecting TFS to TeamCity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18472846/connecting-tfs-to-teamcity)

Unfortunately these did not solve the current issue.

I can successfully connect to (https://bobtbuilder.visualstudio.com) via VS2013 as well as via web browser using the bob.t.builder@live.co.uk credentials.  I have set up the Alternative authentication Credentials and try all combinations, but from the error log below the issue does not appear to be authentication based.

Here is the current error message : -

> TFS failed. ExitCode: 111, command: "D:\Program Files (x86)\TeamCity\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\plugins\tfs\bin\tfs-native.exe" "@@D:\Program Files (x86)\TeamCity\temp\TC-TFS-23-1111_263\command.params", in file: {https://bobtbuilder.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection, /user:***** /password:***** /hash:S, /noProxy, D:\Program Files (x86)\TeamCity\temp\TC-TFS-23-1111_262.result, ConnectionTest, $/Builder}, completed in: 63 second(s)

```
stdout: TFS Native Verifier v8.0 Copyright (C) 2006-2013 JetBrains s.r.o.

Running under .NET Framework 4.0.30319.18408

INFO  - 
INFO  - Use Team Explorer 2013
INFO  - 
TFS Native Accessor v8.0 Copyright (C) 2006-2013 JetBrains s.r.o.
INFO  - Connecting to server https://bobtbuilder.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection
INFO  - WebProxy is disabled

Connection test:
Server='https://bobtbuilder.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection'
Username='##LIVE##bob.t.builder@live.co.uk'
Root='$/Builder'

ERROR - TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from server https://bobtbuilder.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection.

Technical information (for administrator):
Unable to connect to the remote server

System.Exception: TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from server https://bobtbuilder.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection.

Technical information (for administrator):
Unable to connect to the remote server ---> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServiceUnavailableException: TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from server https://bobtbuilder.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection.

Technical information (for administrator):
Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 65.52.8.37:443
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.SendRequestAndGetResponse(HttpWebRequest webRequest, WebException& webException)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.ReadResponse(HttpWebResponse webResponse, WebException webException)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.IsAuthenticationChallenge(TfsMessage requestMessage, HttpWebResponse webResponse, WebException webException, TfsMessage& responseMessage)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.SendRequest()
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpRequestChannel.Request(TfsMessage message, TimeSpan timeout)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.Invoke(TfsClientOperation operation, Object[] parameters, TimeSpan timeout, Object[]& outputs)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.Registration.GetRegistrationEntries(String toolId)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.RegistrationProxy.GetRegistrationEntries(String toolId)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.RegistrationService.RefreshMemoryCache()
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.RegistrationService.RefreshCachesIfNeeded(Boolean direct)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.RegistrationService.GetRegistrationEntries(String toolId)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.PreFrameworkServerDataProvider.FindServiceLocation(String serviceType, String toolId)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.PreFrameworkServerDataProvider.LocationForCurrentConnection(String serviceType, Guid serviceIdentifier)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.EnsureProviderConnected()
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.Disconnect()
at JetBrains.TeamCity.Tfs.TfsLogin.TFSDispose(TfsTeamProjectCollection t) in c:\BuildAgent\work\23f504c63c17dfdf\TfsNativeAccessor\src\TfsLogin_VS12.cs:line 17
at JetBrains.TeamCity.Tfs.TfsLoginBase`1.DoWithAuthenticatedConnection(String server, String username, String password, JBAction`1 action) in c:\BuildAgent\work\23f504c63c17dfdf\TfsNativeAccessor\src\TfsLogin.cs:line 48
at JetBrains.TeamCity.Tfs.Command.Do() in c:\BuildAgent\work\23f504c63c17dfdf\TfsNativeAccessor\src\Command.cs:line 27
at JetBrains.TeamCity.Tfs.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\BuildAgent\work\23f504c63c17dfdf\TfsNativeAccessor\src\Program.cs:line 134
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at JetBrains.TeamCity.Tfs.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\BuildAgent\work\23f504c63c17dfdf\TfsNativeAccessor\src\Program.cs:line 438
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Does this helps? http://davidburela.wordpress.com/2014/04/07/connecting-team-city-to-visual-studio-online-using-git-source-control/

Answer (score 2):

I had almost exactly this problem and it was due to the companies proxy farking it up. You fix it by adding a file called internal.properties in your ***teamcity\data\config***
with

```
teamcity.tfs.useSystemProxy=true
```

Obviously.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response James, but unfortunately I still can't seem to get passed this error.  I doubled checked the location of this file and found this page useful : - <http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Configuring+TeamCity+Server+Startup+Properties#ConfiguringTeamCityServerStartupProperties-TeamCityinternalproperties>?

Comment: Hi MrSteve - Are you able to find a solution for this? I'm facing the same issue. I've VS 2012 Update 4 installed, and have enables alternate authentication credentials as well. It was actually working for me a month ago, but started to see this error now! Thanks!

Comment: Is there an equivalent for Git (connecting to VSO git repo)